# SQL Server - how to dynamically determine financial year?

Tags: sql-server

Every year I have to update my company's financial reports to include the new financial year (as the year isn't coterminus with the calendar year), so I do.....

```
Case
    when ST_date >= '1996.11.01 00:00:00' and st_date  < '1997.11.01 00:00:00' 
    then '96-97'
[etc]
end as year,
```

Every year I have to remember which reports I need to amend - most years I forget one!

...Is there a simple dynamic way to determine this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this example:

```
declare @ST_Date datetime = '20120506'

SELECT
    convert(char(2),DateAdd(m,-10,@ST_DATE),2)+'-'+
    convert(char(2),DateAdd(m,+ 2,@ST_DATE),2) as year
```

As a column expression:

```
    convert(char(2),DateAdd(m,-10,ST_DATE),2)+'-'+
    convert(char(2),DateAdd(m,+ 2,ST_DATE),2) as year
```

Pretty trivial!

The way I handle these problems (financial year, pay period etc) is to recognize the fact that financial years are the same as any year, except they start X months later. The straightforward solution is therefore to shift the FY by the number of months back to the calendar year, from which to do any "annual" comparisons or derivation of "year" (or "month").

Answer (score 6):

You could definitely write a simple **stored function** in SQL Server to determine the financial year based on the date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFinancialYear (@input DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @FinYear VARCHAR(20)

    SET @FinYear = 
        CASE
            WHEN @INPUT >= '19961101' AND @input < '19971101' THEN '96-97'
            WHEN @INPUT >= '19971101' AND @input < '19981101' THEN '97-98'
            ELSE '(other)'
        END

    RETURN @FinYear
END
```

and then just use that in all your queries.

```
SELECT 
    somedate, dbo.GetFinancialYear(somedate)
......
```

If you need to add a new financial year - just update the one function, and you're done !

**Update:** if you want to make this *totally dynamic*, and you can **rely** on the fact that the financial year always starts on Nov 1 - then use this approach instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFinancialYear (@input DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @FinYear VARCHAR(20)

    DECLARE @YearOfDate INT

    IF (MONTH(@input) >= 11)
        SET @YearOfDate = YEAR(@input)  
    ELSE
        SET @YearOfDate = YEAR(@input) - 1

    SET @FinYear = RIGHT(CAST(@YearOfDate AS CHAR(4)), 2) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST((@YearOfDate + 1) AS CHAR(4)), 2)

    RETURN @FinYear
END
```

This will return:

- `05/06` for a date such as `2005-11-25`
- `04/05` for a date such as `2005-07-25`

Comment: @dazzathedrummer If you found this answer solved your issue can you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @FinancialMonth Varchar(100)=NULL,@Month smallint,@Date DateTime='04/06/2013'

BEGIN TRY 
SELECT @FinancialMonth='01-'+IsNULL(@FinancialMonth,'April')+'-'+Cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
SELECT @Month=(Month(Cast(@FinancialMonth as datetime))-1) * -1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,'Invalid Financial Month' ErrorMessage
END CATCH

SELECT Month((CONVERT([varchar](10),dateadd(month,(@Month),@Date),(101)))) FinancialMonth,
Year((CONVERT([varchar](10),dateadd(month,(@Month),@Date),(101)))) FinancialYear
,DatePart(qq,(CONVERT([varchar](10),dateadd(month,(@Month),@Date),(101)))) FinancialQuarter
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me and sets it as the actual FY end date.

`SET @enddatefy = convert(DATE, str(datepart(yyyy,DateAdd(m,-6,@enddate))+1)+'0630',112)
SET @enddatefyid = str(datepart(yyyy,DateAdd(m,-6,@enddate))+1)+'0630'`

Answer (score 0):

```
datename(YEAR,  DATEADD(M,-3,Date)) +'-'+ cast((datepart(YEAR,  DATEADD(M,-3,Date)) + 1) %100 as varchar(2))
```

Calculate on Column 'Date'

Financial year ranges from 1st April to 31st March

Answer (score 0):

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.GetFinancialYear (@input DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @FinYear VARCHAR(20)

    IF (MONTH(@input) > 3)
        SET @FinYear = RIGHT(CAST(Year(@input) AS CHAR(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST((Year(@input) + 1) AS CHAR(4)), 2)
    ELSE
        SET @FinYear = RIGHT(CAST((Year(@input) - 1) AS CHAR(4)), 4) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST(Year(@input) AS CHAR(4)), 2)

    RETURN @FinYear
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @date1 datetime = '2017-07-01'
Select Case 
    When Month(@date1)>=7 Then 'FY'+Convert(NVARCHAR(10),(Right(year(getdate()),2)+1))
    Else 'FY'+Convert(NVARCHAR(10),(Right(year(getdate()),2)))
End
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, where the financial year starts in July.

```
CASE WHEN DatePart(mm, [YourDate]) >= 7 
  THEN convert(varchar(10), YEAR([YourDate])) +' / '+ Convert(varchar(10), YEAR([YourDate]) + 1 )
  ELSE Convert(varchar(10), YEAR([YourDate]) - 1) +' / '+ Convert(varchar(10), YEAR([YourDate]) )
  END AS [Financial Year],
```